# Creating a column with file name for many dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

I'm currently using R studio Version 1.0.143 with R version 3.4.4.

I'm trying to make a apply() function that does the following but to many files:

```
df1 <- read_excel("Sample 1.xlsx")
df1["Sample"] <- "Sample 1"
df2 <- read_excel("Sample 2.xlsx")
df2["Sample"] <- "Sample 2"
rbind(df1, df2) -> final
```

A function that adds a column to the dataframe informing to which sample the variables belong, because after I will bind all samples. Not only this function has to read many excel files, but to add a column in each file with the name of the file (as the example). I couldn't find anything similar in other questions

I tried to use lapply, but without success. I need this because I want to merge more than 100 dataframes (I could do by hand but it seems dumb to not use apply).
All the files have the same columns, so there is no need for a function that puts NAs when a column is not present in one file.

Comment: Reading many files into R is one of the most asked questions on R tagged questions of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
names <- c("Sample 1", "Sample 2")

out_l <- lapply(names, function(x) {
  tmp_df <- read_excel(paste0(x, ".xlsx"))
  tmp_df[["Sample"]] <- x
  tmp_df
})
out_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, out_l)
```

Or using the shorter version per @Parfait's comment

```
names <- c("Sample 1", "Sample 2")

out_l <- lapply(names, function(x) {
  transform(read_excel(paste0(x, ".xlsx")), Sample = x)
})
out_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, out_l)
```

Comment: Or use `transform` or `within` for a one liner inside `lapply`: `transform(read_excel(paste0(x, ".xlsx")), Sample = x)`

Comment: Indeed. I was trying to stick to a similar format as the OP so as to optimize on familiar ground.

Comment: As an fyi, `names` is a vector, not a data frame.

Comment: I tried something a little different so I don't have to create the "names" dataframe. `dta_files <- list.files('C:/Users, pattern = 'Sample', full.names = F)
out_l <- lapply(dta_files, function(x) {
    transform(read_excel(paste0(x)), Sample = x)
})
out_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, out_l)`         This gives me a column with each filename (Sample 1.xlxs), which seems good enough

Comment: Yes, `list.files()` is another useful and common approach.